# How to open an activity from fragment and add toolbar and navigation drawer of fragment's activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a main activity contains a toolbar with navigation drawer, a view pager and tablayout.I setup tabs with view pager, for each tab I have a fragment. The layout for Main activity is like this:

```
Toolbar          navigation menu
/////////
ViewPager
////////
Tabs
```

For one of tabs i have a button that I want when click on it an activity with same toolbar and navigation menu appear. Like this:

```
Toolbar          navigation menu
/////////
activity content
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Really did not understand the second point . Do you want to start an Activity when the button is clicked in one of the Tab ?

Comment: Yes i want to start new activity with same toolbar and navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

when you enter in new activity then add toolbar, drawer and other things which you need it. you can create different XML files for toolbar and others and use PFB

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbarr"/>
```